# SQL Server: Cannot resolve collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "[garbage]"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, functions, collation

So I'm writing a large UDF in T-SQL to be used in reporting. The UDF contains quite a few common table expressions.

At one point I was adding another CTE:

```
 cteCmtCauses AS (
    SELECT ProductId = p.Id,
           Name = hz.Name,
           CMT = CONCAT(IIF(hz.Cmt_c= '1', 'C', ''), IIF(hz.hz.Cmt_m = '1', 'M', ''), IIF(hz.Cmt_t = '1', 'R', ''))
    FROM [redacted]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ProductId = p.Id,
           Name = c.Name,
           --C = c.Cmr_HasCarcinogenicRisk,
           --M = c.Cmr_HasMutagenicRisk,
           --R = c.Cmr_HasToxicForReproductionRisk,
           CMT = CONCAT(IIF(hz.Cmt_c= '1', 'C', ''), IIF(hz.hz.Cmt_m = '1', 'M', ''), IIF(hz.Cmt_t = '1', 'R', ''))
    FROM [redacted]
 ),

 cteCmtCausesConcat AS (
    SELECT ProductId = p.Id,
           ComponentIds = (
                -- Here the issue happens
                SELECT CONCAT(cte.CMT, N'|', cte.Name, dbo.QueryConcatenationString())
                FROM cteCmtCauses cte 
                WHERE cte.ProductId = p.Id
                FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE
           )
    FROM [redacted]
 ),
```

When trying to persist the UDF mutation, I got this error:

```
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Procedure QueryProduct, Line 93
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "널㾍.鉀杫.....祉߾.䊙꛸.鈀杫..." in the concat operation.
```

And in fact on every attempt the message changed a little bit:

```
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "࿠䚋.剀焩.....祉߾.䊙꛸.刀焩..." in the concat operation.
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "꿠䥆.뉀洶.....祉߾.䊙꛸.눀洶..." in the concat operation.
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "꿠洦.퉀洷.....祉߾.䊙꛸.툀洷..." in the concat operation.
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "焐柘.牀䯏.....祉߾.䊙꛸.爀䯏..." in the concat operation.
```

I was able to work around it by using:

```
SELECT CONCAT(cte.CMT, N'|', cte.Name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, dbo.QueryConcatenationString())
```

But the weird thing is, *everything* in the database and tempdb has the same collation: database collation, being `Latin1_General_CI_AS` (except from one of the tables used in the `UNION ALL` which is `Latin1_General_CS_AS`).

[Gist of full reproducible sample](https://gist.github.com/Sebazzz/9e9f3b6823e0fa2eede94b5b8b2527f4), make sure that the database collation is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

How do I *properly* resolve this issue, is this a known bug, and do I need to worry about SQL server silently corrupting my data once I start using this UDF?

Using

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-GDR) (KB3194721) - 11.0.6248.0 (X64) 
    Sep 23 2016 15:49:43 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Business Intelligence Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
```

Answer (score 4):

#### UPDATE

I finally had time to test this and was able to reproduce the problem. While not respecting collation precedence (noted in my original answer below) was *a* problem, it was not *this* problem (though both could be caused by the same underlying bug). Here is what I can now confirm:

1. The O.P.'s test script (via Gist) does not produce this problem as it's missing a critical piece: forcing the collation of one of the `NVARCHAR` "Name" columns in the `Component` and `Statement` tables to be different than the other.
2. The actual error is a collation mismatch between the two "Name" columns in the `UNION ALL`.
3. The collation mismatch in the `UNION ALL` *should have* ended the query before it even got to the `CONCAT` function, and it would have if both columns were `VARCHAR`, but if at least one column is `NVARCHAR`, then the `CONCAT` function prevents the query from terminating properly.
4. There are two ways in which the query can behave improperly when `CONCAT` is involved (at least in this `UNION ALL` scenario):

   1. If the column from the subquery (containing the `UNION ALL` with the collation mismatch) is *not* the first parameter of the `CONCAT` function, then it will terminate with a misleading error message, stating that the error is in the "concat operation" instead of being in the "UNION ALL operation" (oh, and let's not forget about the garbage collation name in the error message!)
   2. If the column from the subquery (containing the `UNION ALL` with the collation mismatch) *is* the first parameter of the `CONCAT` function, then it will  actually *succeed*, using the database's default collation for the value returned by the `CONCAT` function. (see final test case below)
5. The `CONCAT` built-in function was fixed as of SQL Server 2014 as neither this behavior, nor the incorrect behavior shown in the "**Original Answer**" (see below) is reproducible starting with that version (and I tested with 2014, 2016, 2017, and 2019).

```sql
-- DROP TABLE #Mix;
CREATE TABLE #Mix
(
  [VC1]  VARCHAR(50)  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CS_AS,
  [VC2]  VARCHAR(50)  COLLATE Azeri_Cyrillic_100_CS_AS_WS,
  [NVC1] NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE Frisian_100_CS_AI_KS,
  [NVC2] NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE Sami_Sweden_Finland_100_CI_AI
);
INSERT INTO #Mix ([VC1], [VC2], [NVC1], [NVC2]) VALUES (0xB0, 0xDE, 0xDE, 0xDE);
SELECT * FROM #Mix;
/*
VC1    VC2    NVC1    NVC2

░      Ю      Þ       Þ
*/



SELECT CONCAT(N'Both VARCHAR', sub.[WhatEva])
FROM   (
    SELECT [VC1]
    FROM #Mix
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [VC2]
    FROM #Mix
) sub([WhatEva]);
/*
 Msg 457, Level 16, State 1, Line XXXXX
Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed because the
   collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict between
   "Azeri_Cyrillic_100_CS_AS_WS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CS_AS" in
   UNION ALL operator.
*/


SELECT CONCAT(N'At least one NVARCHAR', sub.[WhatEva])
FROM   (
    SELECT [VC1]
    FROM #Mix
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [NVC1]
    FROM #Mix
) sub([WhatEva]);
/*
-- 2012
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line XXXXX
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "{db_default_collation}" and
   "堓.ꚤ鍛翹.堓.툀堗.툀堗.쓀姧.꺱䱷..꺱䱷......꺱䱷..툘堗.帎鍲翹.堓..錿翹..."
   in the concat operation.

-- 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019
Msg 451, Level 16, State 1, Line XXXXX
Cannot resolve collation conflict between "Frisian_100_CS_AI_KS" and
   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CS_AS" in UNION ALL operator occurring in SELECT
   statement column 1.
*/


-- SUCCESS!?!?!?! Should be an error!!!
SELECT CONCAT(sub.[WhatEva], N':At least one NVARCHAR') AS [ConcatSuccessWTF?],
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(CONCAT(sub.[WhatEva], N':At least one NVARCHAR'),
                            'collation') AS [ResultingCollation]
FROM   (
    SELECT [VC1]
    FROM #Mix
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [NVC1]
    FROM #Mix
) sub([WhatEva]);
/*
-- 2012
ConcatSuccessWTF?          ResultingCollation

░:At least one NVARCHAR    {db_default_collation}
Þ:At least one NVARCHAR    {db_default_collation}


-- 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019
Msg 456, Level 16, State 1, Line XXXXX
Implicit conversion of nvarchar value to sql_variant cannot be performed because the
   resulting collation is unresolved due to collation conflict between
   "Frisian_100_CS_AI_KS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CS_AS" in UNION ALL operator.
*/
```

> is this a known bug

Not sure if it was noted in any public forum, but it must have been noticed internally (to Microsoft) since it was fixed as of the next version (i.e. SQL Server 2014), though not in any Service Pack as I tested on SQL Server 2012, SP4 GDR (11.0.7462.6).

> How do I properly resolve this issue

If you, or anyone else, is still using SQL Server 2012 and running into this, it is best to resolve the collation conflict at the source, which is in the `UNION ALL` operation. Just pick the table with the column that has the collation that you do *not* want, and apply the `COLLATE` clause there such that the `UNION ALL` operation succeeds on its own, even if no `CONCAT` function is being used. This is better than specifying the `COLLATE` in the `CONCAT` function because that is after the fact of the `UNION ALL`, which in this case *should* be failing, but is allowed to succeed due to the bug in `CONCAT`.

---

#### ORIGINAL ANSWER

The Collation problem (separate from the error message resulting from the Collation problem) is due to the `CONCAT` built-in function not honoring Collation Precedence, and hence requiring all input parameters to be of the same Collation. Clearly you have one input parameter that is not of the same Collation as the rest. That parameter is `cte.Name`, which you have currently fixed via the `COLLATE` keyword.

We can simulate this scenario as follows. You can run it from any database. The default Collation for the Database that I am executing the following code in is: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

```
CREATE TABLE #TT (Col1 NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_EBCDIC278_CP1_CS_AS);
INSERT INTO #TT values ('something');


SELECT CONCAT('now this is ', tmp.Col1)
FROM #TT tmp;
/*
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 17
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and
    "SQL_EBCDIC278_CP1_CS_AS" in the concat operation.
*/
```

And the following two queries even show that the Collation is evaluated per each input parameter, with the first input parameter setting the Collation to be used:

```
SELECT CONCAT('now this is ', tmp.Col1, N' else' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS)
FROM #TT tmp;
/*
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 23
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and
    "SQL_EBCDIC278_CP1_CS_AS" in the concat operation.
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 23
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and
    "Latin1_General_100_CI_AS" in the concat operation.
*/

SELECT CONCAT('now this is ' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS, tmp.Col1, N' else')
FROM #TT tmp;
/*
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 30
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_100_CI_AS" and
    "SQL_EBCDIC278_CP1_CS_AS" in the concat operation.
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 30
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_100_CI_AS" and
    "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the concat operation.
*/
```

This conflict can be fixed in two ways:

1. Don't use the `CONCAT` built-in function. The main benefit of `CONCAT` is that it doesn't require each parameter to be a string type; it will handle the conversion to string internally. This is convenient if you have several non-string items to concatenate. But if you only have strings, then it doesn't provide any benefit, and probably even hurts performance to pass all of that stuff into the function. AND, by not using `CONTACT`, Collation Precedence will take over, and in most cases resolve the conflict automatically.

   ```
   SELECT 'now this is ' + tmp.Col1
   FROM #TT tmp;
   -- now this is something
   ```

   In this case, Collation Precedence will determine that the Collation of the `tmp.Col1` column overrides the Collation of the string literal (which uses the "current" database's default Collation).
2. Use the `COLLATE` clause (as you are already doing). There is nothing wrong with this approach as this is one of the uses of the `COLLATE` keyword.

   ```
   -- Force the Collation of the column in the temp table to match the "current" database:
   SELECT CONCAT('now this is ', tmp.Col1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
   FROM #TT tmp;
   -- now this is something


   -- Force the Collation of the string literal to match the column in the temp table:
   SELECT CONCAT('now this is ' COLLATE SQL_EBCDIC278_CP1_CS_AS, tmp.Col1)
   FROM #TT tmp;
   -- now this is something
   ```

   In these two cases, the Collation to use is determined by the first input parameter, and either that one needs to be explicitly set to the Collation of the second parameter (bottom example) which in this case is taken from the columns definition. Or, the second parameter needs to be explicitly set to match the Collation of the first parameter (top example) which in this case is taken from the databases's default as it is a string literal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and pointers. Indeed I was aware of the collation issue, but rather worried about some weird bug manifesting in SQL Server.

Comment: @Sebazzz I wouldn't worry about data corruption here. It "looks" like a bug with the error message itself coming from .NET. But I can't imagine there being any silent corruption. I will try your repro script in a little bit. What is the language of the OS set to? Also, have you tried this without the `CONCAT` function and instead just using `+` as I suggested?

Comment: I was worrying about data corruption because SQL obviously outputs random memory. Using concatenation with `+` causes no issues. Language of the OS is in both cases English, and tried with Windows Server 2008R2 and Windows 10.

Comment: @Sebazzz Please run the following query, in the database that has the problem, and post the results: `SELECT os_language_version, DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'LCID') AS [DatabaseLCID], SERVERPROPERTY('LCID') AS [ServerLCID], SERVERPROPERTY('SqlCharSet') AS [SqlCharSet], SERVERPROPERTY('SqlCharSetName') AS [SqlCharSetName], SERVERPROPERTY('SqlSortOrder') AS [SqlSortOrder], SERVERPROPERTY('SqlSortOrderName') AS [SqlSortOrderName], SERVERPROPERTY('CollationID') AS [CollationID], SERVERPROPERTY('Collation') AS [Collation] FROM sys.dm_os_windows_info;`. Thanks.

Comment: @Sebazzz Hi. I know it's been a few years and you are not likely facing this issue now, but I was finally able to reproduce the error and thus determine the exact issue, and recommend the ideal solution (though you weren't far off, and what you did was fine, and wouldn't behave differently than the ideal solution in any practical way). Please see the updates at the top of my answer for details :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a quick workaround then [COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4395/understanding-the-collate-databasedefault-clause-in-sql-server/) will help you get things moving again.

Comment: This is no different than what the O.P. is already doing. The only difference is that the O.P. specified the Database's default Collation.

Comment: @srutzky: The O.P. is specifying the collation and could be choosing the wrong one, database_default automatically figures out which collation is required.

Comment: That is not entirely correct. The O.P. stated: "_I was able to work around it by using..._", hence the O.P. did choose the correct one. And `DATABASE_DEFAULT` will only be correct if that is the Collation that is needed. In _this_ case that is the desired Collation, but that won't always be the case. And if there were parameters to the `CONCAT` function of other Collations, then the "preferred" one could be any of them. It just so happens that here, 3 of the 4 parameters are the database default simply due to being string literals and a UDF return value. But that is _this_ particular case.

Comment: @srutzky: If the O.P. doesn't have the option of changing the collation of the offending table (properly fix) then database_default is a more generic solution that will deal with any other collation issues. I'm not providing a definitive answer, I'm just adding a contribution to the community.

Comment: Tables do not have Collations, columns (and string expressions and variables) do. Either way, why would the O.P. change the collation of the column? There is nothing inherently wrong with the current collation. It is quite likely just fine for that column's typical usage. It just so happens that in this case it is in conflict, and that is fine as it happens often enough. But saying that DATABASE_DEFAULT will "will deal with any other collation issues" is just plain wrong. It could just as easily be that the opposite is needed, that all other parameters should use the columns collation.

Comment: @srutzky: Apologies for using "Table", I was being too generic. In the past I've had to maintain systems that receive data from different collations randomly, and change again when the supplier rolled out the latest upgrade. DATABASE_DEFAULT has been useful in standardising internal Coding Practice and making upgrades go far more smoothly.

Comment: I completely agree that `DATABASE_DEFAULT` is a super-handy option that helps in many cases. My issue here is that it's overly simplistic, especially in relation to the `CONCAT` function which requires all parameters to have a matching Collation. There could be 4 diff Collations with 4 string params, none of them being the DB default. Using DB_DEFAULT, especially with `VARCHAR` data, can even corrupt data if the Collation uses a diff Code Page than what the columns are using. I realize it has made life easy, and don't begrudge anyone that, but setting Collations really needs to be deliberate.

Comment: Please understand that I am not trying / wanting to be negative, and I realize that this can be coming off stronger than intended. There is _a lot_ of misinformation and lack-of-information regarding Collations, encodings, etc and am trying to reduce that by clarifying the details now that I have learned them and realize how many nuances there are with this stuff, that I had no idea about before researching it in depth. And I definitely appreciate people contributing to the community; I just want to make sure that the message that gets across to readers is as accurate as possible :-).

Comment: @srutzky: I think you've provided an excellent answer that focuses on the O.P. (and should be flagged as the solution) I've provided an answer that tries to add content to the community and potentially help anyone with a similar issue should they Google across this question. Cool Beans?